# Status update on fog

Tags: pluggable-transports

[Tor page about pluggable transports](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/PluggableTransports) mentions a neat idea about chaining them; there is project to implement it called [`fog`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/fog.git). As I can see from its gitweb page, the last time anything happened there was about 3 years ago.
I wonder if anyone knows anything newer about its fate and possible future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fog` was a 2014 GSOC project, and after that development was not continued.  So it's effectively dead and the code is rotting away.